# OData cannot find the controller unless the parameter is sent as int

Tags: c#, angularjs, odata

I have this OData controller that works fine for GET and Patch method. However, there's a custom GET method that I had to create in order for use to load the data from a different server and copy to the new one from where the OData retrieves the data. When the user "Retrieves" new data, it sends the date as a parameter. Since it's a new claim for the date, I couldn't put the date in the $filter, hence the new GET method.

This is what the GET method looks like:

```
        [ODataRoute("Claims({key})")]
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions= System.Web.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public HttpResponseMessage ClaimByDate([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);
            string date = key.ToString();
            DateTime claimDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

            if (!ClaimsExistForToday(today))
            {
                GenerateClaimsList(today, claimDate);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);

        }
```

Here's the angularjs controller

```
vm.retrieve = function () {

    if (vm.selectedDate !== null) {
        var day = vm.selectedDate.getDate();
        var date = (day + "" + (vm.selectedDate.getMonth() + 1) + "" + (vm.selectedDate.getFullYear()));

        ClaimService.getClaimsByDate(date)
            .then(function (response) { if (response) activate(); })

        vm.clear();
    }
}
```

Here's the angular function that's sending the get request:

```
function getClaimsByDate(date) { //Angularjs service

    return $http.get("odata/Claims(" + date + ")")
        .then(function (data) {

            return true;
        });
}
```

First Issue: 
The OData GET method have to have "int" for the parameter. I tried with string and DateTime, but when I send the data with 'string' as paramenter, it won't find the controller at all unless the data was sent as integer. And if I send the date as UTC, I get an error as `potentially dangerous` and won't execute.

Second Issue:
Sending date as int, it will find the controller if date is sent as `30112015` in the format ddMMyyyy, but it won't find `1112015` or `01112015`. It seems like it's only recognizing the date greater than 10. Other than this, everything else works fine including the regular GET method with `[EnableQuery]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this SO answer [[Web API and OData- Pass Multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616108/web-api-and-odata-pass-multiple-parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616108/web-api-and-odata-pass-multiple-parameters) which helped me out. I ended up creating a function with the `key` as parameter. Then it was only a matter of calling the function from Angular.