# odata v4 using 2 parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata, odata-v4

I just want to pass 2 parameter into controller and run my sql-function
try and googled a lot resources with no luck,

anyone could give me some hints?

basically i follow this [Web API and OData- Pass Multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616108/web-api-and-odata-pass-multiple-parameters)

when i using `builder.Function` compiler keep tell me no extension method found.

package.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.Functions" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

my WebApiConfog.cs

```
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
using wcod;
using wcod.Model;
namespace wcod
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            //  config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);



            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            // var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            // builder.EntitySet<Booking>("Bookings");
            builder.EntitySet<LiveBooking>("LiveBookings");
            builder.EntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");
            builder.EntitySet<BookingInfo>("BookingInfoes");
            builder.EntitySet<LiveBookingByType>("LiveBookingByTypes");






            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());
            // config.MapODataServiceRoute( routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "odata/v4", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i can , when i use System.web.Odata.Builder, the builder.getEdModel() would get error type., i tried create a static EdmModel, the whole Odata structure are mess up.

Comment: i tried, it return me a blank screen

Comment: works now, the m$ scaffolding the controller with Http one.thank you GWigWam!!!

Comment: Happy to help @user2285201 I have turned my comment into an answer if you'd be so kind as to mark it as 'accepted' that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.Web.OData.Builder` instead of `System.Web.Http.OData.Builder`. It should be in the package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`.

If `.GetEdModel()` throws an exception there might be something wrong with you definition, not with the using.

Answer (score 0):

Well i follow this approach:

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
//using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using wcod.Model;

namespace wcod
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

            builder.EntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");

            var function = builder.Function("GetTimeMarkerSearch");
            function.Parameter<string>("bookID");
            function.Parameter<string>("keywords");
            function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<TimeMarker>("TimeMarkers");
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            //config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());

            config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata/v4", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }

    }
}
```

then in my Controller, mycase TimeMarkersControllers

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GetTimeMarkerSearch(bookID={bookID},keywords={keywords})")]
public IHttpActionResult WhateverName([FromODataUri]string bookID, [FromODataUri]string keywords){
// my logic
}
```