# Get route using OData and custom query options

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

We have a controller which expects some parameters in a get route, but the OData functions like `$top` isn't working.

[According to the docs](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/?#url5.2) it (custom query options) should work fine just declaring the `@` prefix at the custom options but it's not:

- Using `@` as the prefix (as suggested at docs) the parameter `filtro` isn't being filled and get default values to all its properties.
- Using no prefix it's not returning an error but the `$top` function is being ignored and I'm getting too many records to show (2K+).

[There is another answer here on SO to something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616108/web-api-and-odata-pass-multiple-parameters), but we are using OData V3 which has no explicit Edm Model Builders, it's inferred.

Have you guys solved such an issue?

Here is my code:

**GET Request:**

```
~/ProdutosRelevantes?$top=5&
    filtro.Cnpjs[0]=00000000000001&
    filtro.DataInicio=2018-01-01&
    filtro.DataFim=2018-12-01&
    filtro.IndMercado=2&
```

**Controller method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ProdutosRelevantes([FromUri] ParametrosAnalise filtro)
{
    var retorno = GetService().GetProdutosRelevantes(filtro);
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
}
```

> ```
> public class ParametrosAnalise
>   {
>       public Guid IdCliente { get; set; }
>       public string[] Cnpjs { get; set; }
>       public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
>       public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }
>       public EnumEscopoMercado? IndMercado { get; set; }      
>       // Enum declaration
>       public enum EnumEscopoMercado
>       {
>           [Description("INCLUI NACIONAL")]
>           InternoEExterno = 1,
>           [Description("EXTERIOR")]
>           Externo = 2
>       }
>   }
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: I have been using odata v4 4ever so I forget what is/isnot possible in v3. It seems that you should be able to filter your result using odata's `$filter` though or am I wrong (you can in v4). That is *usually* the preferred way to do this. Also is there any difference if you were to write `return Ok(rtorno);` instead?

Comment: In this specific case, it's not that simple to "translate" the object to `$filter` function, there are some business rules to check using the `ParametrosAnalise` object. `Ok(retorno)` have the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have enabled oData with [EnableQuery] decorator in your action?
Or in your HttpConfiguration => config.EnableQuerySupport()?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Comment: You're right. My bad, I've forget to set the attribute `EnableQuery` attribute. Thanks